# Unable to verify the first certificate SQL Docker Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, ubuntu, ssl

I have a SQL docker in Ubuntu server. I follow this instructions for enable the SSL conections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security?view=sql-server-linux-ver15

My certificate is from GoDaddy and i have three files (certname.crt => Principal CRT, gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt, and keyfile.key), in the mssql.conf i reference the principal CRT and the key file.

For SQL i convert the CRT to PEM, changing the extension from CRT to PEM.

I start the docker and this starts normally, and loads the certificate, i can see this in the logs

`The certificate [Certificate File:'/etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem', Private Key File:'/etc/ssl/private/mssql.key'] was successfully loaded for encryption.`

I can connect from SSMS normally, but in NodeJS i tried to connect with the library mssql from NPM, but i have this error:

`ConnectionError: Failed to connect to domainexample.com:port - unable to verify the first certificate`

Comment: The linked instructions are all about self-signed certificates. For CA-issued certificates the .pem file needs to include both the origin cert and the intermediate CA cert. Does the .pem file contain two sets of `---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` and `----END CERTIFICATE----` statements wrapping the contents of `certname.crt` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`?

Comment: The file doesn't have two lines of ---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----, but i have the gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt, that file contains three lines of ---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----, so, i imagine i need to add all certificates, but in what order? First gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt? or first the content of .pem?